# How to compare two arrays and remove data from one array in php?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have 2 arrays of PHP, one having ids of online users and second having ids of idle users, but in idle users array some ids of online user's also exist, i want to compare both arrays and remove user ids from 2nd array in php. how can i do this?

Comment: you mean offline users from idle's array . right?

Comment: or you want to remove those ids who exist in online array?

Comment: i want to remove those ids whic exist in online users array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
$idleWithoutOnline = array_diff($idleUsers, $onlineUsers);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

yes thats possible by array_diff
have a look at
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$array1 = array('[param1]' ,'demo' ,'[param2]' ,'some' ,'[param3]');
$array2 = array('value1'   ,'demo' ,'value2'   ,'some' ,'value3');

array_unique( array_merge($arr_1, $arr_2) );
```

or you can do:

```
$arr_1 = array_diff($arr_1, $arr_2);
$arr_2 = array_diff($arr_2, $arr_1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$online_users = array(1, 5, 7, 8);
$idle_users = array(6, 4, 5, 8, 9);

for($i = 0; $i < count($idle_users); $i++)
{
    foreach($online_users as $v)
    {
        if($idle_users[$i] == $v)
        {
            unset($idle_users[$i]);
        }
    }
}

print_r($idle_users); // This will give you 6,4,9 as idle users
```